# testCafe slowing the tests down after fileUpload

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am automating a data capture form.
The first element of this form is an image file upload control & I'm uploading a 5KB image.
But after this step, the test executes the next step which is writing a text into a textbox & then it halts for nearly 30 seconds.
How to reduce this un-necessary wait?

```
    test('Test 1', async t => {
  await listingPage.uploadImage();
  await listingPage.listAnItem();
  ..
```

**Upload image code**

```
  async uploadImage() {
    await t.setFilesToUpload(this.imageInput, ['../../uploads/photo02.jpg']);
  }
```

** Data entry code block **

```
async listAnItem() {
    await t
      .typeText(Selector('#description'), this.DESCRIPTION) /* --> Application is slowing after this step */
      .click(this.categorySelect)
      .click(Selector('#react-select-2-option-0-0'))
```

**.testcaferc.json file**

```
{
    "browsers": [ "chrome", "safari" ],
    "remoteChromeVersion": "80",
    "src": "specs",
    "reporter": [
      {
        "name": "spec"
      }
    ],
    "speed": 1,
    "debugOnFail": false,
    "skipJsErrors": true,
    "selectorTimeout": 20000,
    "assertionTimeout": 20000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 8000
  }
```

**DOM Snippet of file-upload**

```
<input aria-describedby="error__images" aria-label="Upload an image" tabindex="0" type="file" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" data-testid="imageInput" class="ImageInputstyles__Input-sc-2l692w-7 aosWu">
```

Comment: Could you please clarify if TestCafe shows the "Waiting for element to appear..." message in the browser during this waiting period? Would TestCafe come to a halt at the typeText action if it is not preceded by the file upload?

Comment: @ArseniyRubtsov Yes. It do say "Waiting for element to appear...". But the browser is loaded long before. and it waits for really long.

Comment: Most likely, this behavior is not related to the `setFilesToUpload` action. You can check it omitting this action in your test. Does TestCafe wait before or after the text is written by the `typeText` action? Such delay may occur when the element you need is hidden under another element. If this is the case, you can try setting [offsets](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/click.html#options) for the problematic action. It would be helpful if you send an example illustrating the issue.

Comment: Yes. it seems to be waiting at the drop-down. <div class="listingSelect__single-value css-1uccc91-singleValue">Other</div><div class="css-1g6gooi"><div class="listingSelect__input" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="listingCategoriesBrands__category__select" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-labelledby="error__category" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; value=""><div style="position: absolute visibility: hidden; "></div></div></div>

Comment: @user2451016 I was unable to reproduce the issue with the given markup snippet. Could you please share the entire page that shows the problematic behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue itself was not due to the Upload files control.
Issue was occuring, due to a drop-box, (after uploading file), which was dynamically updating another drop-box that had values populated dynamically based on the value selected in the first drop-down.

Rewriting the drop-down operation something like below resolved the issue:

```
  async fillSubCategoryFields(catType = 'CAT_NAME') {
await t
  .click(this.categorySelect, { timeout: 50 })
  .click(Selector('.listingSelect__option').withText(catType));
```

}